# Algorithm to check if there are certain letters bounded by [cages] and replace them?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace

Hello I am doing the following programming exercise: [The Hunger Games - Foxes and Chickens](https://www.codewars.com/kata/591144f42e6009675300001f). The statement is:

```
Story

Old MacDingle had a farm.

To be more precise, he had a free-range chicken farm.

But Old MacDingle also had a fox problem.

Foxes F eat chickens C

At night the only guaranteed "safe" chickens are in their cages [] (unless a fox has got into the cage with them!)
Kata Task

Given the initial configuration of foxes and chickens what will the farm look like the next morning after the hungry foxes have been feasting?
Examples
Ex1 Before  

CCC[CCC]FCC[CCCCC]CFFFF[CCC]FFFF

After   

...[CCC]F..[CCCCC].FFFF[CCC]FFFF

Ex2 Before  

...[CCC]...[CCCFC].....[CCC]....

After   

...[CCC]...[...F.].....[CCC]....

Ex3 Before  

CCC[CCC]FCC[CCCFC]CFFFF[CCC]FFFF

After   

...[CCC]F..[...F.].FFFF[CCC]FFFF

Notes

    Anything not a fox, a chicken, or a cage is just dirt .
    All cages are intact (not open-ended), and there are no cages inside other cages
```

I have written the following code:

```
public class Dinglemouse {
  public static String hungryFoxes /**/ (String farm) {
    System.out.println("farm: "+farm);
    int posCageStarted = -1;
    int posCageEnded = -1;

    //If there are not cages, and there are foxes, all chickens are cleared; otherwise we keep the farm as it is.
    if(!farm.contains("[") && !farm.contains("]")){
      if(farm.contains("F")){
        return farm.replace("C",".");
      }else{
        return farm;
      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < farm.length(); i++){
      System.out.println("i: "+i);
      char c = farm.charAt(i);
      if(c=='['){
        posCageStarted=i;
      }else if(c==']'){
        posCageEnded=i;
      }

      //If we are between cages ]...[
      if(posCageEnded>posCageStarted){ 
        System.out.println("posCageEnded: "+posCageEnded);
        System.out.println("posCageStarted: "+posCageStarted);
        String betweenCages = "";
        String ending = "";
        String starting = "";
        int nextCageStart;
        if(farm.substring(posCageEnded).contains("[")){
          nextCageStart = posCageEnded+farm.substring(posCageEnded).indexOf('[');
          betweenCages = farm.substring(posCageEnded+1,nextCageStart);
        }else{
          nextCageStart = farm.indexOf('[');
          ending = farm.substring(posCageEnded+1);
          starting = farm.substring(0,nextCageStart);
          betweenCages = ending+starting;
        }
          System.out.println("nextCageStart: "+nextCageStart);
          System.out.println("betweenCages: "+betweenCages);
        if(betweenCages.contains("F")){
          betweenCages = betweenCages.replace('C','.');
          System.out.println("betweenCages: "+betweenCages);
          if(nextCageStart>posCageEnded){
            farm = farm.substring(0,posCageEnded+1) + betweenCages + farm.substring(nextCageStart);
          }else{
            farm = betweenCages.substring(ending.length()) + farm.substring(farm.indexOf('['),posCageEnded+1)
                  + betweenCages.substring(0,ending.length());
          }
          System.out.println("new farm: "+farm);
        }
        i+=betweenCages.length();


      //If we are inside a cage [...]  
      }else if(posCageStarted>posCageEnded){
          System.out.println("inside cage: ");
          System.out.println("posCageStarted: "+posCageStarted);
          System.out.println("posCageEnded: "+posCageEnded);
          int cageEnd = posCageStarted+1 + farm.substring(posCageStarted+1).indexOf(']');
          System.out.println("cageEnd: "+cageEnd);
          String insideCage = farm.substring(posCageStarted+1,cageEnd);
          System.out.println("insideCage: "+insideCage);
          if(insideCage.contains("F")){
            insideCage = insideCage.replace("C",".");
            farm = farm.substring(0,posCageStarted+1) + insideCage + farm.substring(cageEnd);
            System.out.println("new farm: "+farm);
          }
        i+=insideCage.length();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nWe return farm: "+farm);
    return farm;
  }

}
```

And I am quite curious wondering why the random tests are failing:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ExampleTests {

  @Test
  public void ex1() {
    final String before = "CCC[CCC]FCC[CCCCC]CFFFF[CCC]FFFF";
    final String after  = "...[CCC]F..[CCCCC].FFFF[CCC]FFFF";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }

  @Test
  public void ex2() {
    final String before = "...[CCC]...[CCCFC].....[CCC]....";
    final String after  = "...[CCC]...[...F.].....[CCC]....";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }

  @Test
  public void ex3() {
    final String before = "CCC[CCC]FCC[CCCFC]CFFFF[CCC]FFFF";
    final String after  = "...[CCC]F..[...F.].FFFF[CCC]FFFF";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }

  @Test
  public void noCagesTest(){
    final String before = "CCCCCF.CC..C..CC.CF.";
    final String after  = ".....F............F.";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }

  @Test
  public void randomTest3(){
    final String before = ".C......C.F.[...F.]C..CC.....CC.CC[..CFCCC..CCCCCFC....CC...]C[.....C.....C...]";
    final String after  = "..........F.[...F.]...............[...F..........F..........].[.....C.....C...]";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }

  @Test
  public void randomTest1(){
    final String before = "..CCCF....[.CC.CCC.CFFC...C.........C..C.CF..CC]CCCC....[.]";
    final String after  = ".....F....[.........FF....................F....]........[.]";
    assertEquals(after, Dinglemouse.hungryFoxes(before));
  }


}
```

If we pay close attention to test random1, it expects us to substitute ending Chickens. I mean the previous code outputs:

```
.....F....[.........FF....................F....]CCCC....[.]
```

And it should output:

```
.....F....[.........FF....................F....]........[.]
```

Besides when we execute randomTest3 our code outputs:

```
..........F.[...F.]C..CC.....CC.CC[...F..........F..........]C[.....C.....C...]
```

And it should output:

```
..........F.[...F.]...............[...F..........F..........].[.....C.....C...]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: So, to be clear -- you're just asking what you've misunderstood about the problem description, because the expected result for some of the examples is different from what you'd expected?

Answer (score 0):

> At night the only guaranteed "safe" chickens are in their cages [] (unless a fox has got into the cage with them!)

As far as I understand if there are no cages then all chicken die anyway, fox or not, so

```
//If there are not cages, and there are foxes, all chickens are cleared; otherwise we keep the farm as it is.
if(!farm.contains("[") && !farm.contains("]")){
  if(farm.contains("F")){
     return farm.replace("C",".");
  }else{
    return farm;
  }
}
```

should be replaced with

```
//If there are not cages all chickens are cleared
if(!farm.contains("[") && !farm.contains("]")){
  return farm.replace("C",".");
}
```

Another problem with you code is bad detection of situation when we are inside the cage and when we are not. It will be easier to just maintain a single boolean variable `isInsideCage`, setting it to true every time we pass '[' and setting it to false every time we pass ']'.

Instead of `someIndex + farm.substring(someIndex).indexOf(']')` you can use `farm.indexOf(']', someIndex)`.

However, the reason why you code is not working is because you are checking for presence of the fox between cages to eliminate chicken, while chicken outside the cage should be dead in any case. Specifically, you have this line inside if-branch `//If we are between cages ]...[`:

```
       if(betweenCages.contains("F")){
```

Remove this check for the fox.

Right now your code correctly removes all chicken before the first cage, because then both `posCageEnded` and `posCageStarted` are -1, so neither `posCageStarted>posCageEnded` nor `posCageEnded>posCageStarted`, but after the first cage it stops removing chicken outside the cage unless the fox is there as well.

PS. Vote up for 2 fox faces in the comment on line 2 :)